# Record moves to a wrong row on another Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that moves row from one sheet to another one once I time the word "Completed" in a certain field. 
The problem is that it moves row into a wrong place. I have 212 rows on another worksheet, the next row should be moved row #213 on another sheet, but it moves all the way to the row #654. 
Please help me to resove the issue, so each row will move to the next available row on another worksheet.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Sub Autoupdating()
'Move shipments once completed
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("Scheduled Shipments").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Completed Shipments").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Completed Shipments").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Scheduled Shipments").Range("G1:G" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Completed" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed Shipments").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Completed" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: PLease edit your post, remove the current code. Paste your code again, select it and click the {} button.

Comment: FWIW `UsedRange` isn't a reliable way to get the number of rows with data on a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you aren't resetting J when you move from one worksheet to the next. So if you first sheet had 652 rows, it will place the last row on line 653 (J + 1 = 653). But, when you start moving rows on the second sheet, it will start placing them at 654 (653 + 1 = 654).

Comment: Thank you for replying. How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following part into your into your code, removing the commented lines as shown:

```
    'Your previous code ---^
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Completed" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed Shipments").Range("A" & J + 1)
            'xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete 
            'If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Completed" Then
            '    K = K - 1
            'End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    'this is the new code ---v
    For K = xRg.Count To 1 Step -1
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Completed" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next K
    'end of the new code ---^
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Whenever you are feeling that the code you are writing does not do what it intends to do, it is a good idea to simplify.

In this case, you may split the task into two sub-tasks:

- Copy the rows with "Completed" to a specific worksheet
- Delete the rows with the word "Completed"

Note that in order to delete rows correctly from a worksheet, it is a better idea to loop from the bottom and not from the top, thus the loop is reversed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But unfortunately it didn't work. I have only 5 rows in "Scheduled Shipments" sheet and 212 in "Completed Shipments" sheet. For some reason the row moves to row # 654. I just created a new workbook, with 3 rows on one sheet and 3 on the second one and used adjusted code (according to your advice), it moved the row to row #5 on the second sheet, not row #4 as it was supposed to be. Please help.

Comment: @icittar - take a look again, I have uncommented `J` in my code. In general, try debugging with F8, the problem should be easy to solve.